# Plotting a dataset and its fit dynamically

Tags: plotting, manipulate, fitting

I have the dataset

```
vexit = {{4.58204, -0.0403537}, {4.65629, -0.0361285}, {4.73054, -0.0321482}, \
{4.80479, -0.0284244}, {4.87904, -0.0249632}, {4.95329, -0.0217679}, \
{5.02754, -0.018839}, {5.1018, -0.0161757}, {5.17605, -0.0137749}, \
{5.2503, -0.0116318}, {5.32455, -0.00973934}, {5.3988, -0.00808679}, \
{5.47305, -0.00666398}, {5.54731, -0.00546014}, {5.62156, \
-0.00446295}, {5.69581, -0.00366106}, {5.77006, -0.0030341}, \
{5.84431, -0.00255517}, {5.91856, -0.00219723}, {5.99281, \
-0.00193686}, {6.06707, -0.00175508}, {6.14132, -0.00163641}, \
{6.21557, -0.00156781}, {6.28982, -0.00153787}, {6.36407, \
-0.0015364}, {6.43832, -0.00155435}, {6.51257, -0.00158388}, \
{6.58683, -0.00161842}, {6.66108, -0.00165263}, {6.73533, \
-0.0016824}, {6.80958, -0.00170471}, {6.88383, -0.00171748}, \
{6.95808, -0.00171944}, {7.03234, -0.00170997}, {7.10659, \
-0.00168896}, {7.18084, -0.00165669}, {7.25509, -0.00161376}, \
{7.32934, -0.00156097}, {7.40359, -0.00149929}, {7.47784, \
-0.00142979}, {7.5521, -0.0013536}, {7.62635, -0.00127186}, {7.7006, \
-0.00118572}, {7.77485, -0.00109628}, {7.8491, -0.00100463}, \
{7.92335, -0.000911761}, {7.9976, -0.00081861}, {8.07186, \
-0.000726031}, {8.14611, -0.000634788}, {8.22036, -0.000545561}, \
{8.29461, -0.000458939}, {8.36886, -0.000375425}, {8.44311, \
-0.000295434}, {8.51737, -0.000219304}, {8.59162, -0.000147294}, \
{8.66587, -0.0000795934}, {8.74012, -0.0000163281}}
```

What I want is to plot it with its fit to a function of the form `-c/x^6` (where c is a coefficient to find) in the same figure; choosing the fit interval dynamically.

I had already try this:

```
fitted[i_,j_] := Fit[vexit[[i ;; j]], {x^(-6)}, x];
Manipulate[
 Show[ListLinePlot[vexit[[i ;; j]], PlotStyle -> Green], 
  Plot[fitted[i,j], {x, vexit[[i, 1]], vexit[[j, 1]]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]], {i, 20, 40}, {j, 20, 40}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

But i get a lot error messages.
Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The length of your `vexit` is 57, while your function asks from ith to 81th part of it.

Comment: Sorry about that. It wasn't the last version of my code. I corrected it, and the error stills .

Comment: Have a look at [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) and check the behaviour of your Function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, it works fine:

```
Manipulate[
Show[ListLinePlot[vexit[[i ;; j]], PlotStyle -> Green], 
Plot[Evaluate@Fit[vexit[[i ;; j]], {x^(-6)}, x], {x, vexit[[i, 1]], 
vexit[[j, 1]]}], Frame -> True], {i, 20, 40, 1}, {j, 45, 25, 1}]
```